# How to combine an adapter and a view in MergeAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, commonsware-cwac

I am rather new at Android and am having some issues in understanding the usage of cwac-MergeAdapter.

I am trying to use MergeAdapter to populate a spinner; my instance of MergeAdapter should include a SimpleCursorAdapter, which is correctly reading data from my db, and (as a footer) a new TextView (or Button) which should be clickable.

Currently, if I feed the spinner the mergeAdapter containing only data from the db, everything works like a charm; however, as I add the new view, I only get a single, blank entry in the whole spinner. Can someone please help me with this?

Here follows the code:

```
essenceItems = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.db_row_view,
    essenceCursor, from, to);

    TextView addEssence = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    addEssence.setTextColor(R.color.red);
    addEssence.setText("Add new item...");
    addEssence.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addEssence.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    addEssence.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
         startActivityForResult(new Intent(v.getContext(),
         EssencePopup.class), ADD_ESSENCE);

     }
     });
    ma = new MergeAdapter();
    ma.addAdapter(essenceItems);
    ma.addView(addEssence, true);
    spinner.setAdapter(ma);
```

Comment: FYI, as the GitHub repo home page indicates, you need to tag your questions with `commonsware` for me to necessarily pick them up. I will adjust your tag list shortly. "as I add the new view, I only get a single, blank entry in the whole spinner" -- what happens if you call `getCount()` on the `MergeAdapter`? Does it return the right number?

Comment: Thanks for pointing! Yes: getCount() returns 1 after the adapter is added and 2 after also the view is added. However, when I open the spinner, there is still just one blank line.

Comment: That is very strange. If you can create a sample project that demonstrates this error, I would be happy to take a look at it. You can either link to it from this issue (if you can upload it somewhere public) or send it to mmurphy -at- commonsware.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that I will ever support adding individual `Views` to a `MergeAdapter` to be used in a `Spinner`. That would imply that I somehow know how to create a drop-down `View` for some arbitrary `View`.

The workaround I have for you is for you to add the following to your fork of `MergeAdapter`:

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
    int size = piece.getCount();

    if (position < size) {
      return (((SpinnerAdapter)piece).getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent));
    }

    position -= size;
  }

return (null);
}
```

Then, instead of adding an individual `View` via `addView()`, add your own `ArrayAdapter` for your additional data. Be sure to call `setDropDownViewResource()` on all your adapters inside of the `MergeAdapter` -- your sample code never called this, causing some of your other difficulties (e.g., "some entries in the spinner are blank").

It is possible that I will merge this change into `MergeAdapter`, or perhaps will create a `SpinnerMergeAdapter` subclass with it. The blind cast to `SpinnerAdapter` scares me, which is why I want to ponder this a bit more. In light testing, the code I have above seems to work OK.

---

Also, please delete **all** occurrences of `getApplicationContext()` from your code, replacing it with `this` or `WhateverYourActivityNameIs.this` as appropriate. *Only* use `getApplicationContext()` when you know *why* you are using `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and for having taken the time to have a look at my code. I really do understand more now - and the project is working :) Thanks again.